# What is the most efficient Java Collections library?

Tags: java, collections

What is the most efficient Java Collections library?

A few years ago, I did a lot of Java and had the impression back then that [trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) is the best (most efficient) Java Collections implementation. But when I read the answers to the question "[Most useful free Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries)" I noticed that [trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) is hardly mentioned. So which Java Collections library is best now?

**UPDATE:** To clarify, I mostly want to know what library to use when I have to store millions of entries in a hash table etc. (need a small runtime and memory footprint).

Comment: What are the keys and values in this table? If they're not primitives, what's wrong with the normal HashMap etc?

Comment: For a very large map you might want a probing implementation, or even inlined like a database table.

Comment: Interestingly I see no mention of Colt here which was subsequently subsumed into Mahout.

Comment: It is worth to mention very nice collection library - GS collections (github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections). It has excelent documentation and an exhaustive set of mutable and immutable colections

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/time-memory-tradeoff-example

Comment: GS Collections was migrated to the Eclipse Foundation a little over a year ago and is now Eclipse Collections - http://www.eclipse.org/collections/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From inspection, it looks like Trove is just a library of collections for primitive types - it's not like it's meant to be adding a lot of functionality over the normal collections in the JDK.

Personally (and I'm biased) I love [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (including the former Google Java Collections project). It makes various tasks (including collections) a lot easier, in a way which is at least reasonably efficient. Given that collection operations rarely form a bottleneck in my code (in my experience) this is "better" than a collections API which may be more efficient but doesn't make my code as readable.

Given that the overlap between Trove and the Guava is pretty much nil, perhaps you could clarify what you're actually looking for from a collections library.

Comment: should be mentioned that for most tasks google collections is too complex, and java collections are more than sufficient.

Comment: @Andreas: Can't say I agree. Not that it's a "one or the other" scenario - I use the regular collections (with helpers like the Lists class) and then use Iterables etc when I need to. Use the complexity only when it helps you.

Comment: after reading my own comment several months after using G-C extensively - I disagree with my past opinion, and agree fully with yours. use the helper methods/classes extensively, they make much of the code more readable and safer.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for coming back and saying so - I'm glad to hear that GJC is helping :)

Comment: Hey, Jon, Google Java Collections is now [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). You might want to update your post for future references :)

Comment: @ArturCzajka: I'm aware of Guava, it's just that posts two and a half years old do tend to get out of date... I'll edit now.

Comment: I've worked on quite a few data intensive projects where collections were a huge bottleneck.  Java Collections are terribly inefficient (both memory and speed) especially if they store primitives.

Comment: @JayAskren: Yes, any situation where you're boxing a large amount of data is going to be a candidate for optimization. Unfortunately, the OP of this question didn't elaborate on what kind of data they were storing :(

Comment: The question asked what is the most efficient. There is zero evidence presented that Guava is the most efficient.

Answer (score 105):

The question is (now) about storing lots of data, which can be represented using primitive types like `int`, in a Map. Some of the answers here are very misleading in my opinion. Let's see why.

I modified the benchmark from [trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) to measure both runtime and memory consumption. I also added [PCJ](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/) to this benchmark, which is another collections library for primitive types (I use that one extensively). The 'official' trove benchmark does not compare IntIntMaps to Java Collection's `Map<Integer, Integer>`, probably storing `Integers` and storing `ints` is not the same from a technical point of view. But a user might not care about this technical detail, he wants to store data representable with `ints` efficiently.

First the relevant part of the code:

```
new Operation() {

     private long usedMem() {
        System.gc();
        return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
     }

     // trove
     public void ours() {
        long mem = usedMem();
        TIntIntHashMap ours = new TIntIntHashMap(SET_SIZE);
        for ( int i = dataset.size(); i-- > 0; ) {
           ours.put(i, i);
        }
        mem = usedMem() - mem;
        System.err.println("trove " + mem + " bytes");
        ours.clear();
     }

     public void pcj() {
        long mem = usedMem();
        IntKeyIntMap map = new IntKeyIntOpenHashMap(SET_SIZE);
        for ( int i = dataset.size(); i-- > 0; ) {
           map.put(i, i);
        }
        mem = usedMem() - mem;
        System.err.println("pcj " + mem + " bytes");
        map.clear();
     }

     // java collections
     public void theirs() {
        long mem = usedMem();
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(SET_SIZE);
        for ( int i = dataset.size(); i-- > 0; ) {
           map.put(i, i);
        }
        mem = usedMem() - mem;
        System.err.println("java " + mem + " bytes");
        map.clear();
     }
```

I assume the data comes as primitive `ints`, which seems sane. But this implies a runtime penalty for java util, because of the auto-boxing, which is not neccessary for the primitive collections frameworks.

The runtime results (without `gc()` calls, of course) on WinXP, jdk1.6.0_10:

```
                      100000 put operations      100000 contains operations 
java collections             1938 ms                        203 ms
trove                         234 ms                        125 ms
pcj                           516 ms                         94 ms
```

While this might already seem drastic, this is not the reason to use such a framework.

The reason is memory performance. The results for a Map containing 100000 `int` entries:

```
java collections        oscillates between 6644536 and 7168840 bytes
trove                                      1853296 bytes
pcj                                        1866112 bytes
```

Java Collections needs **more than three times** the memory compared to the primitive collection frameworks. I.e. you can keep three times as much data in memory, without resorting to disk IO which lowers runtime performance by magnitudes. And this matters. Read [highscalability](http://highscalability.com/) to find out why.

In my experience high memory consumption is the biggest performance issue with Java, which of course results in worse runtime performance as well. Primitive collection frameworks can really help here.

So: No, java.util is not the answer. And "adding functionality" to Java collections is not the point when asking about efficiency. Also the modern JDK collections do **not** "out-perform even the specialized Trove collections".

Disclaimer: The benchmark here is far from complete, nor is it perfect. It is meant to drive home the point, which I have experienced in many projects. Primitive collections are useful enough to tolerate fishy API - **if** you work with lots of data.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is misleading. Storing ints vs Integers is very different, and most likely the main reason for the increased memory usage. I agree a raw type collection framework could be useful, but it doesn't make trove or pcj "better" than java.util.

Comment: The question is about storing int data efficiently. Not about storing Integers. For this task trove/pcj are more efficient, as I tried to show. Using Integers imposes runtime and memory inefficiencies. Since java.util doesn't allow usage of primitives, it is not the best choice for this task.

Comment: (for Russian community) here goes another benchmark: http://total-holywar.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-collections-framework.html

Comment: Not sure if we don't use int as key,just normal String. What will be the workbench result for them?

Comment: @ClarkBao (sorry for being late) Storing any object as key will use the object `hashCode()`. It gets you an `int` as the key.

Answer (score 51):

I know this is an old post and there are a ton of answers here. 
But, The answers above are superficial and over simplified in terms of suggesting a library. There is no one library that does well across the various benchmarks presented here. The only conclusion I derive is if you care about performance and memory and specifically dealing with primitive types, its more than worth looking at the non jdk alternatives.

Here is a more sound analysis, in terms of benchmark mechanics and the libraries covered.
[This](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-dev/201103.mbox/%3CAANLkTimgGKApQd=FtBA-bXpr+=b8W-Fg0axC5aUAED6Z@mail.gmail.com%3E) is a thread in the mahout dev list.

The libraries covered are

- HPPC
- Trove
- FastUtil
- Mahout ( Colt )
- Java Collections

*Update June 2015*:
Unfortunately, the original benchmarks are no longer available and besides its a bit outdated. 
[Here](http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/) is a fairly recent (Jan 2015) benchmarks done by someone else. It is not as comprehensive nor does it have the interactive exploratory tools as the original link.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful .. considering the importance of the question it's hard to believe none of the other answers (other than the.duckman's) actually answer this question.

Answer (score 20):

As other commentators have noticed, the definition of "efficient" casts a wide net. However no one has yet mentioned the [Javolution library](http://javolution.org/).

Some of the highlights:

- Javolution classes are fast, very fast (e.g. Text insertion/deletion in O[Log(n)] instead of O[n] for standard StringBuffer/StringBuilder).
- All Javolution classes are hard real-time compliant and have highly deterministic behavior (in the microsecond range). Furthermore (unlike the standard library), Javolution is RTSJ safe (no memory clash or memory leak when used with Java Real-Time extension).
- Javolution's real-time collection classes (map, list, table and set) can be used in place of most standard collection classes and provide additional functionality.
- The Javolution collections provide concurrency guarantees to make implementation of parallel algorithms easier.

The Javolution distribution includes a benchmark suite so you can see how they stack up against other libraries/the built-in collections.

Answer (score 16):

Some collection libs to consider:

- Java collections in java.util
- [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) library
- [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)
- [High-scale lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib) from Cliff Click
- Doug Lea's [collections](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/collections/index.html) lib - no longer supported and mostly rebuilt in JDK

I would first and foremost reach for the JDK collection library.  It covers most common things you need to do and is obviously already available to you.

Google Collections is probably the best high-quality library outside the JDK.  It's heavily used and well supported.

Apache Commons Collections is older and suffers a bit from the "too many cooks" problem but has a lot of useful stuff as well.

Trove has very specialized collections for cases like primitive keys/values.  These days we find that on modern JDKs and with the Java 5+ collections and concurrent use cases, the JDK collections out-perform even the specialized Trove collections.

If you have really high concurrency use cases, you should definitely check out stuff like the NonBlockingHashMap in the high-scale lib, which is a lock-free implementation and can stomp on ConcurrentHashMap if you have the right use case for it.

Comment: "These days we find that on modern JDKs and with the Java 5+ collections and concurrent use cases, the JDK collections out-perform even the specialized Trove collections."

Misleading - I have never seen a micro-benchmark where storing/retrieving primitive types in a specialized primitive-collection class like Trove didn't outperform the JDK collection classes in both memory usage and CPU time. 

If you are using objects though (and not primitive types), then I would agree with Alex, fretting over collection impl is not as big of a deal.

Comment: This statement was based on heavy real-world usage (which I'll take over a micro-benchmark any day) of various collection impls where we had prior needed a Trove collection but were able to now pull it out.  Late JDK 6 updates (circa late 2009) actually provided custom code for common map keys like Integer that have substantially improved some of the most common uses.

Comment: Alex, I don't doubt in your specific use-cases that pulling out primitive collections and going with JDK collections was fast enough, but waving your hand across the landscape that is collections and saying "All ye that pass, it is fast enough!" isn't accurate.

If I am working on a 2D game engine, the overhead of boxing/unboxing my primitive types constantly is measurably expensive.

If I'm working on a REST API then no, it probably doesn't make a measurable different at all with respect to much more expensive ops like the HTTP I/O.

I just felt compelled to quantify your post is all.

Comment: I don't think anyone reading this should listen to either of us.  They should test their own use case and see what has the best performance.  My comments are based on my team's fairly aggressive performance tests with a variety of libraries. YMMV.

Comment: I agree with @Riyad. I'm writing a high-performance finite automata suite and have implemented it with both Trove and the Java Collections Framework (jdk 6 latest update). Trove outperforms big time. In the order of tens of times better in both computation speed and memory consumption.

Answer (score 6):

**`java.util`**

Sorry for the obvious answer, but for most uses, the default [Java Collections](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) are more than sufficient.

Comment: For basic uses, yes. But I think the framework misses some basic and advanced features (like immutable collections, filters, multimaps, etc) and that's where (for example) Google Collections comes in

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. The JCF was probably awesome in 2002 when people didn't use use Java for much. Unfortunately it hasn't aged well, especially when compared to the collections support from other JVM languages.

Comment: -1 The question is "most efficient for storing int" and any mentioned example is better than java.util

Answer (score 6):

To store millions of `String` in a map, take a look at http://code.google.com/p/flatmap

Comment: +1 Can you introduce how it enhanced?

Comment: There should be blog posts by the author of flatmap somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

I'm developer of happy-collections from [happy-collections on source-forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/happy-guys/files/)

1. Event based collections
2. Unmodifiable
3. SortedList
4. Cache

Answer (score 3):

[ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)  as well as the `java.util.concurrent` package should be mentioned, if you plan to use the HashMap in multiple threads. small memory footprint is assued, since this is part of standard java.

Answer (score 3):

Trove offers a few advantages.

- smaller memory footprint, it doesn't used Map.Entry objects
- you can use hash strategies instead keys for maps, this saves memory and means you don't need to define a new key each time you want to cache an object on a new set of its attributes
- it has primitive collection types
- think it has some form of internal iterator

That said, a lot has been done to improve jdk collections since trove was written.

It's the hashing strategies that make it appealing to me though... Google for trove and read their overview.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how we define "efficient".

Every data structure has its own Big-Oh behavior for reading, writing, iterating, memory footprint, etc.  A linked list in one library is likely to be the same as any other.  And a hash map will be faster for reading O(1) than a linked list O(n).

> But when I read the answers to the question "Most useful free Java libraries?" I noticed that trove is hardly mentioned.

This doesn't sound like "most efficient".  It sounds like "most popular" to me.

Just some feedback - I've never heard of it, and I don't know anyone who has used it.  Collections built into the JDK, Google, or Apache Commons are well-known to me.

Comment: "Big O" is only one measure of efficiency. But if you look at the Trove website is says "... and so reduces the O (big-oh) in the performance of the hashtable algorithm". Data structures don't have a Big O; algorithms do.

Comment: Aren't you clever.  This answer is almost 15 years old.  Is there nothing better you can do to improve your 8,598 reputation here?  "behavior for reading, writing, iterating" - I think this phrase makes it clear that I was referring to the algorithmic behavior of the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store millions of records in a hash table, chances are that you will run into memory problems. This happened to me when I tried creating a map with 2.3 million String objects, for example. I went with [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html), which is very mature and performs well. They have a Java API that wraps the Collections API, so you can easily create arbitrarily large maps with very little memory footprint. Access will be slower though (as it is stored on disk).

**Follow-up question**: is there a decent (and efficient), well maintained, library for immutable collections? Clojure has excellent support for this, and it would be nice to have something similar for Java.

Comment: Google collections adds immutable Collections.