# Most efficient Java primitive collections library

Tags: java, performance, collections, primitive-types

What is the best Java primitive collections library? (most memory and time efficient)

I've found Trove and [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) to be the most used ones, but haven't found much comparison between them (or between others)

Is there any comparison available?

Comment: I will if there isn't one. :) But I also want to know if there is any other then Trove and FastUtil worth benchmarking.

Comment: you should probably include `java.util` collections as a reference point, along with Apache commons collections and Google commons collections / guava where there are equivalents.  The problems are going to be 1) comparing like functionality with like functionality, 2) measuring memory usage and 3) avoiding the standard traps that typically cause Java "micro-benchmarks"  to give bogus results.

Comment: Memory usage of any non-primitive collection makes it useless in my case. 
And in any case they are certainly all slower too, so they don't fit the request. I don't need any additional functionality, just plain efficient map/set/list etc.

Comment: Someone has already asked [What is the most efficient java collections library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629804/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-collections-library) You may want to start looking there. Matt

Comment: I saw that, but it is more general and unspecified question.

Comment: @Stephen C Probably because doing such a microbenchmark is quite hard. You must build the libraries, learn how to use them, and collect measurements. Most people get the microbenchmark very wrong.

Answer (score 16):

[This comparision](http://b010.blogspot.com/2009/05/speed-comparison-of-1-javas-built-in.html) between Java standard collections, Trove and Colt might be helpful.

Comment: the link is broken ..unable to open in chrome/ie

Comment: Another comparison http://java.dzone.com/articles/time-memory-tradeoff-example

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any good primitive-only framework benchmark. This one would be nice to see, as well as to compare with non-primitive versions (just to show how epically Java generics with autoboxing suck in some hardcore cases).

There's a benchmark [from the Trove itself](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/benchmarks.shtml), I think the most straightforward way is to port it to couple of other libraries.

Also - not sure you've seen that one - [Cern's Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/list/package-summary.html#Overview) library had primitive lists and matrices even before trove emerged AFAICR.

Comment: The Colt link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 5):

I recently open sourced Banana, which is another primitives collections java library.
the difference than the other libraries is that Banana got it's own memory management, which basically allow it to implement any dynamic data structure without creating many objects.
Banana is also much smaller than many of the other libraries, jar is around 60k at the moment.

It already support a LinkedList, which I don't think any other primitive collections library is providing, and I plan to add a Set and a Tree soon.

https://github.com/omry/banana

Comment: Hi there, amazing library. Have you done the Set yet ?

Comment: Nope, but if you want to give it a stab I can help you.
maybe even spend some time on it in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your generosity, but im not in a hurry for this Set support. I didnt notice that this is for primitive collections, as i was looking for arbitrary object collections.