# Multimap Space Issue: Guava

Tags: java, database, hashmap, guava

In my Java code, I am using Guava's Multimap ([com.google.common.collect.Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)) by using this:

```
 Multimap<Integer, Integer> Index = HashMultimap.create()
```

Here, Multimap key is some portion of a URL and value is another portion of the URL (converted into an integer). Now, I assign my JVM 2560 Mb (2.5 GB) heap space (by using Xmx and Xms). However, it can only store 9 millions of such (key,value) pairs of integers (approx 10 million). But, theoretically (according to memory occupied by `int`) it should store more.

Can anybody help me,

1. Why is `Multimap` using lots of memory?  I checked my code and without inserting pairs into the `Multimap`, it only uses 1/2 MB of memory.
  2.

**Is there another way or home-baked solution to solve this memory issue?** Means, Is there any way to reduce those object overheads as I want to store only int-int? In any other language ? Or any other solution (home-baked preferred) to solve issue I faced, means DB based or something like that solution.

Comment: Did you take object overhead into account when working out the "theoretical" size? You're using Integer, not int...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am really sorry. Thanks.

Comment: No problem - and of course you *can't* use `int` as a generic type argument in Java. You probably want a dedicated int to int multimap to avoid the overhead :(

Comment: @JonSkeet,  Is there any way to reduce those object overheads as I want to store only int-int? In any other language ? Or any other solution (home-baked preferred) to solve issue I faced means DB based or something like that solution.

Comment: In a CLR language, you'd be able to write the equivalent of Multimap in a generic form without the overhead, yes. I would imagine the same is true for various "native" languages too. In the JVM you'd have to have a specific type just for `int` to `int`.

Comment: You may also find this of interest: http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a huge amount of overhead associated with `Multimap`. At a minimum:

- Each key and value is an `Integer` object, which (at a minimum) doubles the storage requirements of each `int` value.
- Each unique key value in the `HashMultimap` is associated with a `Collection` of values (according to [the source](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/search?q=AbstractSetMultimap.java&origq=AbstractSetMultimap.java&btnG=Search%20Trunk), the `Collection` is a `Hashset`).
- Each `Hashset` is created with default space for 8 values.

So each key/value pair requires (at a minimum) perhaps an order of magnitude more space than you might expect for two `int` values. (Somewhat less when multiple values are stored under a single key.) I would expect 10 million key/value pairs to take perhaps 400MB.

Although you have 2.5GB of heap space, I wouldn't be all that surprised if that's not enough. The above estimate is, I think, on the low side. Plus, it only accounts for how much is needed to store the map once it is built. As the map grows, the table needs to be reallocated and rehashed, which temporarily at least doubles the amount of space used. Finally, all this assumes that `int` values and object references require 4 bytes. If the JVM is using 64-bit addressing, the byte count probably doubles.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But is there any way to reduce those above listed overheads as I want to store only int-int? In any other language ? Or any other solution (home-baked preferred) to solve issue I faced means DB based or something like that solution.

Comment: @Arpssss There's [this list maintained by NIST](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/) of Java numerics libraries. Many of them support primitive collections, but I don't know of any that support multimaps. According to some studies (e.g., [this one](http://b010.blogspot.com/2009/05/speed-comparison-of-1-javas-built-in.html)), these libraries are vastly faster, but don't save all that much space. Take a look also at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307622/java-primitive-collections-library).

Comment: FYI, I'm on the Guava team and working on a long-term project to reduce the large memory overhead of e.g. `HashMultimap`.  So it'll get improved in the future.  That said, `HashSet` on its own has _huge_ memory overhead.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Since Hashset is part of the JFC, is the plan to simply avoid using it? It would be interesting to see what the alternative would be.

Comment: `HashSet` as written is a well-known memory hog that just internally delegates to a `HashMap`, with all the extra memory overhead of having a value attached to each key.  I'm doing a Guava-internal rewrite, basically.

Comment: "Each Hashset is created with default space for 8 values.". Note that you could reduce this amount by using the alternative factory method: `HashMultimap.create(int expectedKeys, int expectedValuesPerKey)`

Comment: Louis, surprising as it may sound, there is no extra overhead due to the unnecessary "value" field per entry, due to alignment. (I've already tried to copy HashMap's code, drop "value", and make a HashSet, and the memory footprint was exactly the same, modulo a constant handful of words)

Comment: @eneveu, fyi in the next release, the default of 8 becomes a default of 2!

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest way to minimize the memory overhead would be to potentially mix [Trove's](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) primitive collection implementations (to avoid memory overhead of boxing) and Guava's `Multimap`, something like

```
SetMultimap<Integer, Integer> multimap = Multimaps.newSetMultimap(
  TDecorators.wrap(TIntObjectHashMap<Collection<Integer>>()),
  new Supplier<Set<Integer>>() {
    public Set<Integer> get() {
      return TDecorators.wrap(new TIntHashSet());
    }
  });
```

That still has the overhead of boxing and unboxing on queries, but the memory it consumes just sitting there would be significantly reduced.

Comment: Nice way to solve. However, Is not it create performance issue ?

Comment: It shouldn't create any more of a performance issue than you would experience with a normal `Multimap`, and would involve _much, much_ less of a performance penalty than your proposed alternate file-backed solution.

Comment: +1 for Trove. Note that the code could be shortened thanks to the [TDecorators](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TDecorators.html) static factory methods. Thanks to type inference, `new TIntObjectMapDecorator<Collection<Integer>>(new TIntObjectHashMap<Collection<Integer>>())` becomes `TDecorators.wrap(new TIntObjectHashMap<Collection<Integer>>())`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a sparse boolean matrix.  [Sparse matrices / arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java) should provide pointers to library code.  Then instead of putting (i, j) into the multimap, just put a 1 into the matrix at [i][j].

Comment: Yeesh. With this scheme, it would be expensive to return all the values for a given key. You'd have to scan an entire matrix row and collect the indices of the columns containing 1.

Comment: @TedHopp, no.  That's true in a dense matrix but not in a sparse matrix.  A good sparse matrix class should have a way to enumerate the non-zero cells.  In scipy you use [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy-sparse-lil-matrix-nonzero) for this.

Comment: Point taken in principle -- there's probably a way to use a row slice view of a sparse matrix to get the values. Then something like `nonzero` could retrieve the desired list of values. However, the Java libraries that I know of don't have analogues to `nonzero`.

Comment: @TedHopp, [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/SparseDoubleMatrix2D.html#forEachNonZero%28cern.colt.function.IntIntDoubleFunction%29) does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use probably an ArrayListMultimap, which requires less memory than a HashMultimap, since ArrayLists are smaller than HashSets. Or, you could modify Louis's Trove solution, replacing the Set with a List, to reduce memory usage further.

Some applications depend on the fact that HashMultimap satisfies the SetMultimap interface, but most don't.