# Issue with Hash Map Space and Performance

Tags: java, ehcache, h2, berkeley-db, tokyo-cabinet

I have to store more than 100 millions of key-values in my HashMultiMap (key can have multiple values). Can anybody help me which one is faster for both storing and searching:

1) [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)

2) [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/blog/promenade.cgi?id=7)

3) [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

4) [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/)

5) Or anyothers

Another point, is performance of those approximately identical to in-memory hash map ? A little bit guidance will be more helpful. Thanks.

NB: information about any one of these is also helpful.

Comment: What size are your key/values?  What structure do they have?

Comment: @JeffFoster,  key/values are int.

Comment: @JeffFoster, more specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930347/multimap-space-issue-guava

Comment: Are your ints randomly distributed over the 32bit space?  I don't see why you couldn't store it all in memory (with a hand-written unboxed implementation of MultiMap).  Alternatively you could try Redis.

Comment: @JeffFoster, yes, distributed. I have to provide very limited memory to my JVM (2GB). If I want to store 100 millions ints, it will take more than 3 GB.

Comment: @JeffFoster, is Redis is a nice one from others ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [Redis](http://redis.io/).  It's more of a data structure store than the others (e.g. it supports maps and sets) and requires very little effort to get started with.  It's incredibly 
simple to use and has a great [Java API](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis).

I'd start by looking at the functions [here](http://redis.io/commands#hash) that allow you to associate a key with a group of values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. From your experence,  is performance of Redis is approximately identical to in-memory hash map ?

Comment: It'll depend on your circumstances.  I've never had a problem with performance in Redis.  Best advice would be to hack together a prototype and just see what happens.  See also http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at [leveldb](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), because it claims to be [faster than Kyoto Cabinet](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/benchmark.html). Other interesting libraries are [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/), and [JDBM3](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3).

Those are low level libraries (without support for relational queries or SQL). Some offer transactional support, but I'm not sure if you need it. Still, in-memory hash maps are faster.