# Redis: Beginners Issue

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have to store more than 100 millions of key-values in my HashMultiMap (key can have multiple values). Now, I want to use [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki) for that. I download it from [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/downloads) - Jedis 2.0.0.0.jar as recomended to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944582/issue-with-hash-map-space-and-performance). Now, after little bit searching, I could not find any nice document that helps me as a beginner:

1) How to use Jedis (specifically, do I have to treat it as normal .jar files in java ex. like Guava) ?

2) How to implement HashMultiMap (key can have multiple values) in Redis ?

3) How to perform all insertion, searching etc. in Redis.

4) I found by searching Redis, many options like Jedis, Redis, Jredis etc. What are those variations ? And which one would me nice to me for solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944582/issue-with-hash-map-space-and-performance) ?

Any information and/or link to any document will be helpful for me. Sorry, if any stupid questions I ask, because I have no idea about Redis. So, beginning idea will be valuable for me. Thanks.

Comment: Redis has a user manual, Jedis has a project page. You should start at the source, since we're only going to redirect you back there.

Comment: Also, you should ask one question per question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a simple way to achieve what you want. Redis only has normal hashes. One key - one value.

However, you can serialize your multiple values to a string and store *that* as a value. Of course, you lose ability to individually insert/update/remove items, you'll have to reset the whole value every time. But this might not be a problem for you.

Comment: OK.. So, every time I have to take value of the key (for collision) and append it in the string. No inbuilt way ?

Comment: I was thinking more of json strings, but you can do this also.

Answer (score 1):

Redis has few internal types like [lists or sets or associated hashes.](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) I guess you can use  sets for your case. It's better that serializing whle data because operations with internal types are atomic, and you will not need to worry about possible race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

1. check out https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki and  http://redis.io/commands
2. there are several ways which imply using list/sortedSet/hashs as a single fields of your multimap. Then
   a) make of subdatabases to provide separated namespaces i.e. limit what is your overall multimap ( [select](http://redis.io/commands/select) . and/or
   b) use the rich semantics the keys have in redis ( see example [here](http://redis.io/commands/keys) ). You could make up your multimap simply using regular key/value mappings set/get with the key name additionally describing your map fields. You have a variety of options to get what you want. One of the last resorts is scripting.
3. Depends!
4. afaik, jedis is the most mature.