# How to implement Disk Based Hash Map using MongoDB-Java

Tags: mongodb

I have to store more than 100 millions of key-values in my HashMultiMap (key can have multiple values). Can anybody help me, is this possible to implement using Java-MongoDB ? Is the performance of MongoDB approximately identical to in-memory hash map ? Pointer to some nice tutorial about how to create and maintain HashMap in MongoDB is also helpful to me.

Comment: Title of your question is not at all helping. Try to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Ok, I improved it a little bit more. `mongodb` is in the tags, and nobody cares that you are beginner. if you want to stress it, put into question text, not question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I don't know how is your HashMultiMap is going to work, but in MongoDB you basically store objects in JSON (enhanced binary JSON, technically speaking).

So your document could look like this:

```
{
  key1: [value1, value2, value3, ...],
  key2: [value1, value2, value3, ...],
  ...
}
```

If that's gonna work for you - great.

Comment: Yah, I exactly want that structure with high performance in insertion and search for key. Is MongoDB a nice one than others ?

Comment: Can you kindly inform from where I should start ? Actually, I want HashTabale/BTree for that and using Java.

Comment: If you store one key per document than searching will be great. Insert performance [might be not as great](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor), but should be good.

Comment: You start by downloading MongoDb and beginning to code :) Oh, and reading docs is also important.

Comment: Sorry, is it nice for solving this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930347/multimap-space-issue-guava).. From your experience :)