# Trying to create a hash table in java using string as key & double as value

Tags: java, string, double, hashtable

In the following program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashTableStringdouble
{
//  private Hashtable<String, double[]> model  = new Hashtable<String, double[]>();;
    private Hashtable<String, double> model  = new Hashtable<String, double>();;                // this does not work

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

having double[] works but not double. It gives the following error:

*HashTableStringdouble.java:7: error: unexpected type
    private Hashtable model  = new Hashtable();;            // this does not work
                              ^
  required: reference
  found:    double
HashTableStringdouble.java:7: error: unexpected type
    private Hashtable model  = new Hashtable();;            // this does not work
                                                                     ^
  required: reference
  found:    double
2 errors*

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Please explain how does a Hashtable works.

Comment: You have to use `Double`. `double` is a primitive type.

Comment: You are not allowed to use primitives in generics.
Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types

Comment: Generics cannot take primitive values in Java. (Just highlighting that what you're trying to do is not `HashTable` specific.)

Comment: @user714965 what if we use `double[]` ? We can use double[] but it should be array object of primitive data type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use a primitive as a key or value in a Hashtable, you need to use an object. It would work with `Double` instead of `double` for example. The reason why it works with `double[]` is that arrays are objects in Java.

Also, Hashtable is somewhat obsolete and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is preferred in most situations:

```
private Map<String, Double> model  = new HashMap<String, Double>();
//or if you use Java 7+
private Map<String, Double> model  = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Don't use `Hashtable`; use `HashMap`. `Hashtable` is a leftover from Java 1.0, before the times of the Collections Framework.
2. This is not about how maps work in Java, but how Java works in general. You cannot substitute a primitive type for a reference type anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the Double class instead of "native" double

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't use primitive types in `Collection`s. `Collection`s can contain only descendants of `Object` type. If you need collections with primitives, you should look at this question: [Most efficient Java primitive collections library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307622/java-primitive-collections-library).
2. Use `HashMap`, not `Hashtable`. If you are sure, you need a synchronized collection, have a look at `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. E.g.:

   Map model = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

Answer (score 1):

Use wrapper classes. That's one of the reasons why the are invented in the first place.

```
private Hashtable<String, Double> model  = new Hashtable<String, Double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashTableStringdouble
{
  private Hashtable<String, Double> model  = new Hashtable<String, Double>();


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Double` instead of `double`.  In Generic primitive data types are not allowed 
 and don't forget to mark correct answer which you have accepted. welcome to stackoverflow.
If you use `double[]` then it means this is double array `object` (only objects can be there in generic)
and when you use `double` it means primitive double

Comment: Why you are asking me in the comments of the question? You seem to know this.

Comment: @user714965 wanted to make sure that we are on the same page.