# Using SparseIntArray instead of HashMap <Integer, Integer> with putSerializable

Tags: java, android

When I use a `HashMap` with an `Integer` key and data values in Android I get this message in Eclipse:

```
Use new SparseIntArray(...) for better performance
```

Now the problem is that `SparseIntArray()` doesn't implement the `Serializable` interface and can't be used with `getSerializable()` and `putSerializable()` in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

1. How important is using `SparseIntArray()` instead of the `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`?
2. Should I go through the trouble of making `SparseIntArray` serializable? (My first idea is making a wrapper class that implements `Serializable`, is this the right way to go?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> 1) How important is using `SparseIntArray` instead of the `HashMap` ?

It depends on how you are using it.  But unless you are trying to represent many and/or large "arrays" like this, the difference is unlikely to be significant.

Note that Java SE doesn't have any sparse array classes, and it is not normally an issue.

> 2) Should I go through the trouble of making `SparseIntArray` serializable? (My first idea is making a wrapper class that implements `Serializable`, is this the right way to go?)

See above, and below.

Implementing a wrapper sounds reasonable ... if you need to go to this trouble.  Another approach might be to declare a serializable subclass of `SparseIntArray`.  It would be advisable to declare custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods.

---

The `SparseIntArray` class ([source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0b285499db739ba50f2f839d633e763c70e67f96/core/java/android/util/SparseIntArray.java)) uses a pair of `int` arrays to represent the keys and values in the mapping, and uses binary search to do the lookup.  The keys are kept in order with no "holes" and lookup is performed using binary search.  This means the following:

- Memory usage for a `SparseIntArray` will be roughly a factor of 10 less that for an equivalent `HashMap`.  This is due to a combination of things:

  - the hash table array holds roughly 1 reference per entry (depending on how full the table is ...),
  - the keys and values have to be "boxed" as `Integer` objects in a `HashMap`, and
  - each entry in a `HashMap` requires a "node" object that is fairly heavy weight - 4 fields in the standard implementation.

  (However, if you create the `Integer` objects the right way, the "boxing" overhead can be mitigated by the effects of the `Integer` classes instance cache.)

  By contrast, the sparse version requires `2 * capacity` 4 byte words.
- Lookup (i.e. `get`) is `O(logN)` compared with `O(1)` for a `HashMap`.
- Random insertion is `O(N)` compared with `O(1)` for a `HashMap`.  (This is because an insertion has to move on average half of the existing entries so that the new entry can be added at the correct position in the arrays.)
- Sequential insertion (i.e. in ascending in key order) is `O(1)`.

So "which is best" clearly depends on what you are optimizing for, how you use the data structure, and how big it is going to get.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` is that every key and value needs to be boxed. The impact of this can range from nothing to being a heavy load on the system from huge amounts of garbage generation and/or memory use (not to mention the slight performance penalty of boxing/unboxing values). (These concerns have also driven the development of several third-party [collection frameworks for primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307622/java-primitive-collections-library).)

If you decide that the benefits of `SparseIntArray` are worth having, then I think your approach of a wrapper class is reasonable. An alternative would be to make it implement `Parcelable`, which can also be used to save/restore the instance state.