# Should we use HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

A HashSet is backed by a HashMap. From it's JavaDoc:

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance)

When taking a look at the source we can also see how they relate to each other:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Therefore a `HashSet<E>` is backed by a `HashMap<E,Object>`. For all HashSets in our application we have one reference object `PRESENT` that we use in the `HashMap` for the value. While the memory needed to store `PRESENT` is neglectable, we still store a reference to it for each value in the map.

Would it not be more efficient to use `null` instead of `PRESENT`? A further consideration then is should we forgo the `HashSet` altogether and directly use a `HashMap`, given the circumstance permits the use of a `Map` instead of a `Set`.

My basic problem that triggered these thoughts is the following situation: I have a collection of objects on with the following properties:

- big collection of objects > 30'000
- Insertion order is not relevant
- Efficient check if an item is contained
- Adding new items to the collection is not relevant
  The chosen solution should perform optimal in the context to the above criteria as well as minimize memory consumption. On this basis the datastructures `HashSet` and `HashMap` spring to mind. When thinking about alternative approaches, the key question is:

> How to check containement efficiently?

The only answer that comes to my mind is using the items hash to calculate the storage location. I might be missing something here. Are there any other approaches?

I had a look at various issues, that did shed some light on the issue, but not quietly answered my question:

- [Java : HashSet vs. HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261457/java-hashset-vs-hashmap)
- [clarifying facts behind Java's implementation of HashSet/HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849809/clarifying-facts-behind-javas-implementation-of-hashset-hashmap)
- [Java HashSet vs HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689517/java-hashset-vs-hashmap)

I am not looking for suggestions of any alternative libraries or framework to address this, but I want to understand if there is an other way to think about efficient containement checking of an element in a `Collection`.

Comment: Why use `null`? AFAIK, `containsKey` in `HashMap` checks if `get` returns `null`, so this would break a few things.

Comment: 1) It could be a problem to store "null" in HashMap - it breaks a contract 2) I think that "null" reference requires the same amount of memory as reference to any other object, so there is no profit.

Comment: Part of the question is exactly that point: Why not use `null` as value in the `HashMap`?

Comment: @hotzst `null` and `PRESENT` require the same amount of memory (both require 32 bits). But with `PRESENT` the implementation of HashSet is easier. For example, the implementation of `HashSet.add()` would be more cumbersome if `null` was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes you should use HashSet. It might not be the most possibly efficient Set implementation, but that hardly ever matters, unless you are working with huge amounts of data.

In that case, I would suggest using specialized libraries. EnumMaps if you can use enums, primitive maps like Trove if your data is mostly primitives, a bunch of other data-structures that are optimized for certain data-types, or even an in-memory-database.

Don't get me wrong, I'm someone who likes performance-tuning, too, but replacing the built-in data-structures should only be done when its really necessary. For most cases, they work perfectly fine.

What you could do, in case you really want to save the last bit of memory and do not care about inserting, is using a fixed-sized array, sorting that and doing a binary search every time. But I doubt that it's more efficient than a HashSet.

Comment: Your answer triggered another question: [what is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java), which for Java is already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtables and HashSets should be used entirely different, so maybe the two shouldn't be compared as "which is more efficient". The hashset would be more suitable for the mathematical "set" (ex. {1,2,3,4}). They contain no duplicates and allow for only one null value. While a hashmap is more of a key-> pair value system. They allow multiple null values as well as duplicates, just not duplicate key vales. I know this is probably answering "difference between a hashtable and hashset" but I think my point is they really can't be compared.

Comment: What question are you answering?