# How should I map string keys to values in Java in a memory-efficient way?

Tags: java, memory, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for a way to store a string->int mapping. A HashMap is, of course, a most obvious solution, but as I'm memory constrained and need to store 2 million pairs, 7 characters long keys, I need something that's memory efficient, the retrieval speed is a secondary parameter.

Currently I'm going along the line of:

```
List<Tuple<String, int>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple<String, int>>();
list.add(...); // load from file
Collections.sort(list);
```

and then for retrieval:

```
Collections.binarySearch(list, key); // log(n), acceptable
```

Should I perhaps go for a custom tree (each node a single character, each leaf with result), or is there an existing collection that fits this nicely? The strings are practically sequential (UK postcodes, they don't differ much), so I'm expecting nice memory savings here.

Comment: Try to follow the principal of do the easiest thing, unless tests show it's too slow. Your binary search method should work, but have you tested HashMap memory consumption?

Comment: I did - and with `HashMap`, the program sometimes explodes with `OutOfMemoryException` when reloading the data. I'm hoping I can avoid this with a better choice of data structure.

Comment: Use TreeMap. You have the memory benefit of a binary search tree with the programming convenience of a map lookup. Look at my reply below.

Comment: Is your whole system running out of memory or only your Java VM? Is this something that will be done by a lot of 'users' or will this run on a dedicated machine? Simply adding a few gigs of mem might be the cheapest ('easiest') solution.

Comment: Also, does this list change a lot? Or is it actually baked only once (in a while)? Is it sorted upfront? Depending on these answers, you could think of flattening the whole thing to disk and run a binary search with file-seeks. I did it once, worked quite well. It's quite on the far end of the speed-memory trade off, but that was basically what you asked for.

Comment: The node-per-character tree is better known as a "trie."

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Edit**: I just saw you mentioned the String were UK postcodes so I'm fairly confident you couldn't get very wrong by using a Trove *TLongIntHashMap* (btw Trove is a small library and it's very easy to use).

**Edit 2**: Lots of people seem to find this answer interesting so I'm adding some information to it.

The goal here is to use a map containing keys/values in a memory-efficient way so we'll start by looking for memory-efficient collections.

The following SO question is related (but far from identical to this one).

[What is the most efficient Java Collections library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629804/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-collections-library)

*Jon Skeet* mentions that Trove is *"just a library of collections from primitive types"* [sic] and, that, indeed, it doesn't add much functionality.  We can also see a few benchmarks (by *the.duckman*) about memory and speed of Trove compared to the default Collections.  Here's a snippet:

```
                      100000 put operations      100000 contains operations 
java collections             1938 ms                        203 ms
trove                         234 ms                        125 ms
pcj                           516 ms                         94 ms
```

And there's also an example showing how much memory can be saved by using *Trove* instead of a regular Java *HashMap*:

```
java collections        oscillates between 6644536 and 7168840 bytes
trove                                      1853296 bytes
pcj                                        1866112 bytes
```

So even though benchmarks always need to be taken with a grain of salt, it's pretty obvious that *Trove* will save not only memory but will always be much faster.

So our goal now becomes to use Trove (seen that by putting millions and millions of entries in a regular *HashMap*, your app begins to feel unresponsive).

You mentioned 2 million pairs, 7 characters long keys and a String/int mapping.

2 million is really not that much but you'll still feel the "Object" overhead and the constant (un)boxing of primitives to Integer in a regular HashMap{String,Integer} which is why Trove makes a *lot* of sense here.

However, I'd point out that if you have control over the "7 characters", you could go even further: if you're using say only ASCII or ISO-8859-1 characters, your 7 characters would fit in a long (*).  In that case you can dodge altogether objects creation and represent your 7 characters on a long.  You'd then use a Trove *TLongIntHashMap* and bypass the "Java Object" overhead altogether.

You stated specifically that your keys were 7 characters long and then commented they were UK postcodes: I'd map each postcode to a long and save a tremendous amount of memory by fitting millions of keys/values pair into memory using Trove.

The advantage of Trove is basically that it is **not** doing constant boxing/unboxing of Objects/primitives: Trove works, in many cases, directly with primitives and primitives only.

*(*) say you only have at most 256 codepoints/characters used, then it fits on 7*8 == 56 bits, which is small enough to fit in a long.*

Sample method for encoding the `String` keys into `long`'s (assuming ASCII characters, one byte per character for simplification - 7 bits would be enough):

```
long encode(final String key) {
    final int length = key.length();
    if (length > 8) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "key is longer than 8 characters");
    }
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += ((long) ((byte) key.charAt(i))) << i * 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So just to dumb this down a notch, you essentially wind up with two sets of data to work with. The set which maps from the String keys to a long key then the actual data set which uses the long key and the int data. That is still searchable because its trivial to map the String key to a long key but its more memory efficient because longs and ints have less overhead as primitives. Is that close?

Comment: @Adamski: thanks ; )   Keep in mind that you don't just need to use Long/Integer: you also **must** use a library like Trove if you want a hashmap backed by primitives and primitives only.  This way you'll save a lot of memory.

Comment: @Freiheit: yup that is basically it.  But you don't really need a "set of data" to do the String <---> int mapping: you can just use a method *postcodeToInt()* and another method *intToPostcode()*.  Trove is really, much, much more efficient because it's a library backed by primitives only, specifically for this type of use (millions of entries etc.).  And it's really easy to use: it's basically one *.jar* to add to your project.

Comment: @skolima: thanks for adding the *encode(...)* method.  Now someone should add the *decode(...)*   : )

Comment: I think that you can comment now. :) Great answer.

Comment: A nice alternative to Trove is the Apache Mahout Collections. The purpose is the same, collections with primitive types. Which is better I do not know but would like to see them compared.

Answer (score 25):

**Use the Trove library.**

The [Trove library](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) has optimized `HashMap` and `HashSet` classes for primitives.  In this case, `TObjectIntHashMap<String>` will map the parameterized object (`String`) to a primitive `int`.

Comment: This is a good answer but I would have thought that the String storage overhead completely dwarfed the space saved in using ints instead of Integers.

Comment: That's why in addition to using Trove (which is definitely the way to go, I +1'ed Erick's answer) you also do a String-to-long mapping with the postcode and use not a *TObjectIntHashMap{String}* but a *TLongIntHashMap*.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 9):

First of, did you measure that `LinkedList` is indeed more memory efficient than a `HashMap`, or how did you come to that conclusion? Secondly, a `LinkedList`'s access time of an element is `O(n)`, so you cannot do efficient binary search on it. If you want to do such approach, you should use an `ArrayList`, which should give you the beast compromise between performance and space. However, again, I doubt that a `HashMap`, `HashTable` or - in particular - a `TreeMap` would consume that much more memory, but the first two would provide constant access and the tree map logarithmic and provide a nicer interface that a normal list. I would try to do some measurements, how much the difference in memory consumption really is.

**UPDATE**: Given, as Adamski pointed out, that the `String`s themselves, not the data structure they are stored in, will consume the most memory, it might be a good idea to look into data structures that are specific for strings, such as [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (especially [patricia tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)), which might reduce the storage space needed for the strings.

Comment: From Collections.binarySearch() docs: `If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.`

Comment: Ok, so that would indicate `O(n)` access to me then, which is pretty slow for 2million items. But the op changed it ArrayList in the meantime anyway :)

Comment: After reading this (and other) great answers, I'm going with http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/ Patricia Trie implementation.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is a [succinct-trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120) - a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which stores its data in *nearly* the least amount of space theoretically possible.

Unfortunately, there are no succinct-trie classes libraries currently available for Java.  One of my next projects (in a few weeks) is to write one for Java *(and other languages)*.

In the meanwhile, if you don't mind [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), there are [several](http://code.google.com/p/taiju/) [good](http://www-tsujii.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~hillbig/tx.htm) native succinct-trie libraries you could reference.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I've not used them but they may fit with what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

A custom tree would have the same complexity of `O(log n)`, don't bother. Your solution is sound, but I would go with an `ArrayList` instead of the `LinkedList` because the linked list allocates one extra object per stored value, which will amount to a lot of objects in your case.

Answer (score 4):

As Erick writes using the Trove library is a good place to start as you save space in storing `int` primitives rather than `Integer`s.

However, you are still faced with storing 2 million String instances.  Given that these are keys in the map, interning them won't offer any benefit so the next thing I'd consider is whether there's some characteristic of the Strings that can be exploited.  For example:

- If the `String`s represent sentences of common words then you could transform the String into a `Sentence` class, and intern the individual words.
- If the Strings only contain a subset of Unicode characters (e.g. only letters A-Z, or letters + digits) you could use a more compact encoding scheme than Java's Unicode.
- You could consider transforming each String into a UTF-8 encoded byte array and wrapping this in class: `MyString`.  Obviously the trade-off here is the additional time spent performing look-ups.
- You could write the map to a file and then memory map a portion or all of the file.
- You could consider libraries such as Berkeley DB that allow you to define persistent maps and cache a portion of the map in memory.  This offers a scalable approach.

Comment: Those are UK postcodes, so there's a huge overlap between their values - they are practically sequential.

Comment: That is awesome.  I will post another answer with suggested solution.

Comment: @Adamski: ah ah, you wrote your answer while I was writing mine... I simply suggest a mapping "UK postcode -> long" and hence he can use Trove and a TLongIntHashMap fully backed by primitives and primitives only : )

Answer (score 4):

maybe you can go with a [RadixTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.util.TreeMap` instead of `java.util.HashMap`. It makes use of a red black binary search tree and doesn't use more memory than what is required for holding notes containing the elements in the map. No extra buckets, unlike HashMap or Hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to step a little outside of Java. If you have that many values, you should use a database. If you don't feel like installing Oracle, SQLite is quick and easy. That way the data you don't immediately need is stored on the disk, and all of the caching/storage is done for you. Setting up a DB with one table and two columns won't take much time at all.

Comment: I can't believe no one else has suggested that a dataset that large belongs in a database.

Comment: @Thor84no In college I ported a data-mining algorithm from Java into a single SQL query. It was admittedly hard to read/maintain, but it ran >100 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using some **cache** as these often have the **overflow-to-disk** ability.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a key class that matches your needs.  Perhaps like this:

```
public class MyKey implements Comparable<MyKey>
{
    char[7] keyValue;

    public MyKey(String keyValue)
    {
        ... load this.keyValue from the String keyValue.
    }

    public int compareTo(MyKey rhs)
    {
        ... blah
    }

    public boolean equals(Object rhs)
    {
        ... blah
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        ... blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
OptimizedHashMap<String, int[]> myMap = new OptimizedHashMap<String, int[]>();
for(int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
{
  myMap.put("iiiiii" + i, new int[]{i});
}
System.out.println(myMap.containsValue(new int[]{3}));
System.out.println(myMap.get("iiiiii" + 1));
```

---

```
public class OptimizedHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>
{
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    if(value != null)
    {
        Class<? extends Object> aClass = value.getClass();
        if(aClass.isArray())
        {
            Collection values = this.values();
            for(Object val : values)
            {
                int[] newval = (int[]) val;
                int[] newvalue = (int[]) value;
                if(newval[0] == newvalue[0])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what? That looks slower AND less memory efficient than a normal HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Actually HashMap and List are too general for such specific task as a lookup of int by zipcode. You should use advantage of knowledge which data is used. One of the options is to use a prefix tree with leaves that stores the int value. Also, it could be pruned if (my guess) a lot of codes with same prefixes map to the same integer.

Lookup of the int by zipcode will be linear in such tree and will not grow if number of codes is increased, compare to O(log(N)) in case of binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are intending to use hashing, you can try numerical conversions of the strings based on ASCII values.
the simplest idea will be

```
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        sum+=(int)arr[i];

    }
```

hash "sum" using a well defined hash functions. You would use a hash function based on the expected input patterns.
e.g. if you use division method

```
    public int hasher(int sum){
       return sum%(a prime number);
    }
```

selecting a prime number which is not close to an exact power of two improves performances and gives better uniformly hashed distribution of keys.

another method is to weigh the characters based on their respective position.

e.g: if you use the above method, both "abc" and "cab" will be hashed into a same location. but if you need them to be stored in two distinct location give weights for locations like we use the number systems.

```
     int sum=0;
     int weight=1;
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         sum+= (int)arr[i]*weight;
         weight=weight*2; // using powers of 2 gives better results. (you know why :))
     }
```

As your sample is quite large, you'd avoid collisions by a chaining mechanism rather than using a probe sequence.
After all,What method you would choose totally depends on the nature of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is objects' memory overhead, but using some tricks you can try to implement your own hashset. Something like [this](https://intelligentjava.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/memory-efficient-hashset-implementation-for-java/). Like others said strings have quite large overhead so you need to "compress" it somehow. Also try not to use too many arrays(lists) in hashtable (if you do chaining type hashtable) as they are also objects and also have overhead. Better yet do open addressing hashtable.