# Java library with more data structures

Tags: java

Can anyone point me to some good Java library (jar) that has some more data structures other than what comes as part of standard Java language. I want support for things like - Tuple, Pair, Tries, Binomial/Fibonacci trees and may be Graphs. [Yes, I know writing them on my own will be lot of fun, but I am reluctant to reinvent the wheel right now]

Comment: Check this post with discussions on various thirdparty libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629804/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-collections-library/630864#630864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a number of additional data structures, as well as the [Apache Commons Collections library](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any single Java library that contains all of those components. There is however a very good library called [**JGraphT**](http://www.jgrapht.org/) which provides a very nice and comprehensive API for graphs in Java. It also includes some structures that are related to that such as a `FibonacciHeap` class. They also have a very comprehensive [JavaDoc](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/). The feature list from the JGraphT website lists:

> - **directed** and **undirected** graphs.
> - graphs with **weighted** / **unweighted** / labeled or any user-defined edges.
> - various edge multiplicity options, including: **simple-graphs**, **multigraphs**, **pseudographs**.
> - **unmodifiable** graphs - allow modules to provide "read-only" access to internal graphs.
> - **listenable** graphs - allow external listeners to track modification events.
> - **subgraphs** graphs that are auto-updating subgraph views on other graphs.
> - all compositions of above graphs.

Answer (score 4):

The [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) library/framework has most (all? maybe not pair) of those, even though it's a visualization library (and a really nice one at that).

Comment: This seems more like a visualization library. I was more searching for an Algorithm/Data Structure library - something similar to Boost libraries in C++! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user396089 That's because that's what it is (and I said as much). I wasn't aware that *where* the classes were mattered to you, I assumed you were just interested in having the classes. How does it matter?