# Is it possible to avoid unchecked casting when calling `clone()`?

Tags: java, casting, compiler-warnings

This is a contrived example to illustrate the problem. I know there are [ways around this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252819/276232) that don't generate compiler warnings and you can also disable the warning. I'm wondering if this is possible without any of those tricks.

Given this code:

```java
1 public static void main(String[] args) {
2    Map<String,String> map = null;
3
4    HashMap<String,String> hmap;
5
6    if(map instanceof HashMap)
7        hmap = (HashMap<String,String>)map;
8    else
9        hmap = new HashMap<String,String>(map);
10
11   map = (Map<String,String>)hmap.clone();
12
13    Object o = hmap.clone();
14    if(o instanceof Map<?,?>)
15        map = (Map<String,String>)o;
16 }
```

The code on both lines 11 *and* 15 generate the compiler warning:

```
Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,String>
```

Line 11 is a little understandable: `Object.clone()` returns an `Object`, and there has been no `instanceof` check prior to casting. The programmer *knows* that the clone will be a `Map<String,String>`, but the compiler can't prove it.

Line 15 is puzzling to me, though. Usually, checking the type of a variable using `instanceof` and then immediately casting it will not generate such a warning. Indeed, replacing the code with non-parameterized classes like this will generate no warnings, on either of these lines of code:

```java
static class A {}
static class B extends A implements Cloneable {
    public Object clone() { return null; }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = null;

    B b;

    if(a instanceof B)
        b = (B)a;
    else
        b = new B();

    a = (A)b.clone();

    Object o = b.clone();
    if(o instanceof A)
        a = (A)o;
}
```

Back to the original code (with the `Map<String,String>` references), even adding this awkward construction to the end of the code generates a similar warning:

```java
map = (Map<String,String>)hmap.getClass().cast(o);
```

The warning this time is `Unchecked cast from capture#11-of ? extends HashMap to Map<String,String>`. Trying to write:

```java
map = HashMap<String,String>.class.cast(o);
```

Generates a compiler **error** because it can't figure out that `HashMap<String,String>.class` is a static class reference in the same way that e.g. `HashMap.class`, so we have to use a reference of the "correct" type to call `Class.cast`.

Is this something that Java just can't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something that Java just can't do?

Yes, it's how it is by design.

Look at java sources (1.8) of HashMap clone method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Object clone() {
    HashMap<K,V> result;
    try {
        result = (HashMap<K,V>)super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
        throw new InternalError(e);
    }
    result.reinitialize();
    result.putMapEntries(this, false);
    return result;
}
```

It uses `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` for the same purposes to suppress warning on `super.clone()` .

You can not completely avoid it but if your code has a lot of clone() methods you can minimize these warnings  by extracting to method like :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String,String> cloneWithoutWarning(HashMap<String,String> map) { return (HashMap<String,String>) map.clone(); }
```

Comment: This is a good example. Presumably, if it were possible to avoid suppressing the warning, the code for `HashMap.clone` would use that technique. Not exactly proof-positive, but definitely illustrative. In my case, I used a local reference and suppressed the warning on only that reference (rather than the whole method).

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, checking the type of a variable using instanceof and then immediately casting it will not generate such a warning.

This is not true. `instanceof`s have no effect on casting warnings.

This is not a warning about possible `ClassCastException` from this cast. Unchecked cast means Java cannot do the cast safely. That means cast might pass without `ClassCastException` yet the type is not a match. This might result in `ClassCastException` from unexpected place.

This is a real issue in this case. `HashMap.clone()` returns `Object` for backwards compatibility. There is no way to tell, if its implementation is type safe. For example:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap() {
            @Override
            public Object clone() {
                HashMap o = (HashMap)super.clone();
                o.put("x", new Object());
                return o;
            }
        };
        Map<String,String> copy = (Map<String,String>)map.clone(); // will pass
        System.out.println(copy.get("x")); // no cast but fails with ClassCastException
    }
}
```

`clone()` is problematic. If possible, just create a new `HashMap`.

If you have to use clone only use safe casts:

```
Map<?, ?> copy = (Map<?, ?>)map.clone();
System.out.println((String)copy.get("x")); // explicit cast will fail
```

Unless you are dealing with legacy code (non-generic) unchecked casts should be considered hacks/workarounds.

Comment: But even calling `Class<Something>.cast(obj)` still generates a warning, even though it's got all the right generic magic in it. There are some cases where these warnings *must* be suppressed in order to get them to go away. You can't code around them.

Comment: `Class.cast` has the same problem as regular cast. You can cast to HashMap<?,?> but the type of elements is gone at runtime and cannot be checked.

Comment: Aha, the problem is with the use of specific generic types. Casting to `Map<?,?>` compiles without any warning *even without an instanceof check*. Using the anonymous generic type (`<?>`) forces the programmer to acknowledge that type-erasure exists and accept responsibility for its effects.