# Why is HashSet in Java taking so much memory?

Tags: java, memory, hashset

I'm loading a 1GB ASCII text file with about 38 million rows into a HashSet. Using Java 11, the process takes about 8GB of memory. ​

```
HashSet<String> addresses = new HashSet<>(38741847);
​try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    lines​.forEach(addresses::add);
​}
​System.out.println(addresses.size());
​Thread.sleep(100000);
```

Why is Java taking so much memory?

In comparison, I've implemented the same thing in Python, which takes only 4GB of memory.

```
s = set()
with open("test.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    s.add(line)
print(len(s))
time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: A `HashSet` normally has an overhead of 32 bytes/element, for starters...

Comment: What version of Java? Using Java 9 or later might [cut in half](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) the amount of memory used to represent your text.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm using Java 11

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836546/fastest-java-hashsetinteger-library), where I also discovered a few alternative HashSet implementations which are part of the
[trove4j](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove/src/master/), [hppc](https://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html) and Guava libraries. I've tested them with the same code. Here the results:

trove4j (5.5GB)

```
THashSet<String> s = new THashSet<>(38742847,1);
```

hppc (4.7GB)

```
ObjectHashSet <String> s2 = new ObjectHashSet<>(38742847,1, 0.99);
```

Guava (5GB)

```
ImmutableSet<String> s2    
ImmutableSet.Builder<String> b =  ImmutableSet.builder();
lines.forEach(b::add);
s2 =b.build();
```

I decided for Guava, because it doesn't need to know the exact number of elements to be inserted. So I don't have to count the lines of the file first.

Comment: An `ObjectIdentityHashSet` isn't going to be helpful, since it won't deduplicate or anything.  You might also try a Guava `ImmutableSet`, which has about a third of the overhead of a `HashSet`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks! It should work with `ObjectHashSet` instead of `ObjectIdentityHashSet`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashSet` has a load factor which defaults to 0.75. That means memory is reallocated once the hashset is 75% full. If your hash set should hold 38741847 elements, you have to initialize it with 38741847/0.75 or set a higher load factor:

```
new HashSet<>(38741847, 1); // load factor 1 (100%)
```

Comment: Even with load factor 1 it takes 7.4 GB.