# ArrayLists and HashMaps are recommended to use in Java?

Tags: java, performance, perl, arraylist

Im coming from Perl where Hashes and Arrays are comfortable to use since they are very dynamical and do lots of stuff in the background which usually would annoy the programmer.

Similar to this i start to use hashmaps and ArrayLists since they make the programming work a litte bit easier and faster. But how is the perfomance? Is it recommended to use these types of data for larger projects or should i only limit myself to the core of Java with strings and arrays?

Thanks for all answers:-)))

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/629804/1065197

Comment: It is better to use classes with data types, not for performance reasons, but for clarity and maintainability. BTW Objects are much faster and use far less memory.

Comment: Yes and no. I created `PerlArray` and `PerlHash` to do the type of things I like to do with Perl arrays and hashes. If I'm going to use Java arrays, I pretty much manage them in an `ArrayList`. But hash lookups are not going to be near as fast as what basically amounts to a *struct*, where the offset can be stored directly in the bytecode. I don't always program in Java, but when I do, I use objects for data and containers for relationships and algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unchanging data that you will write to once (or few times) and read many times, an array may be (very slightly) faster than an `ArrayList`. An array might also consume (marginally) less memory than an `ArrayList`. However, `ArrayList` in particular is a class used very often so it is useful to be able to work with it (and more generally with other classes that implement the `List` interface), and underneath it, the elements are stored in an array so accesses should not **really** be slower.

`HashMap`s implement a hashing-based map. They are typically an `O(1)` access data structure and implementation so they are indeed recommendable. As a class implementing the `Map` interface, they are also a useful way of mapping one object to another, which is a commonly encountered problem.

Most `Collections` classes (and interfaces) are well designed and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap`, `ArrayList`, etc are part of the core Java libraries and are recommended for use.

You should investigate the other `Collection`s as well though, since depending on what you are doing some of the other options may be even better for you.