# Why do not Java Generics support primitive types?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vector

The following is an example of an error that is incorrectly specified. How should I fix it and why did I get an error?

`Vector <int> vi = new Vector <int> ();`

Comment: You can not use primitive types in Generics. int primitive data type while Integer is a Wrapper class, so you have to use Vector <Integer> vi = new Vector <Integer> ();

Comment: *why did I get an error?* - what error? Whenever you ask a question be specific and post the exact error message so we don't have to guess what you are asking.

Comment: As a side note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629804/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-collections-library

Answer (score 2):

Java generics don't support primitive types like `int`. You can use the `java.lang.Integer` wrapper class instead:

```java
Vector <Integer> vi = new Vector<Integer>();
```

As a side note, while `Vector` isn't officially deprecated, it's been considered outdated since JDK 1.2, and you should probably use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.